# The operation failed because an index or statistics with name already exists on table EF6.1

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I used entityframework 6.0.2 and every thing work very nice,

but when i update entityframewrok to 6.1.1 application throw following exception :

The operation failed because an index or statistics with name  already exists on table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After one hour i found solution

i used "Add-migration" when my Entity framework's version was 6.0.2 but migration structure is different  in EF 6.1.1 ,

So , i delete migrations class and use "add migration" again.

every thing is ok now

Regards

Comment: Great! It work. Thank you for your post. I have been stuck here for an hour.